# unable to edit Textbox in MVC for Firefox 4.0.1 , working fine in IE7

Tags: model-view-controller

We have textbox on our MVC view. Once we load data, we are unable to edit text of textbox in firefox 4.0.1 where as it is working fine in IE7 and later. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check orders and count of  <link> tag  to Css Files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had some CSS class which was prevented in FF.